# Setting single cell value to NaN with replace in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I have the following dataframe:

```
In [96]: df1
Out[96]:
   a  b   c
   0  1  1  26
   1  1  2  38
   2  1  3  17
```

If I use the replace method to replace a value with Nan on the whole dataframe it works:

```
In [97]: df1.replace(2, np.nan, inplace=True)

In [98]: df1
Out[98]:
   a    b   c
0  1  1.0  26
1  1  NaN  38
2  1  3.0  17
```

But if I try to replace a single cell value with Nan it does not work:

```
In [101]: df1.iloc[1:2,0:1].replace(1, np.nan, inplace=True)

In [102]: df1
Out[102]:
   a    b   c
0  1  1.0  26
1  1  NaN  38
2  1  3.0  17
```

What is the reason for this behavior.

Comment: try this: `df1.iloc[1:2,0:1] = np.nan` or simply `df1.iloc[1,1] = np.nan`

Comment: `df1.iloc[1:2,0:1]` is a copy. Even though you pass `inplace=True`, it does the operation in place for the copy.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the great comments.  You can forgo the `inplace=True` and just reassign the results

```
df1.iloc[1:2, 0:1] = df1.iloc[1:2, 0:1].replace(1, np.nan)

df1

     a    b   c
0  1.0  1.0  26
1  NaN  NaN  38
2  1.0  3.0  17
```